# Magento2 : How to add confirmation alert to custom field in

Tags: grid, magento2.2.3, alert, confirmation

I have created custom admin grid,`I wish to add confirmation alert popup` while clicking my custom field (like before deleting,before update status).Please provide me a solution

```
I need to show the confirm alert like below
```

[image]

Comment: if you got this please reply here.

Comment: are you trying to add a message in `massaction` or `columnaction`?

Comment: Try with a given answer and let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Have you got solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Let's explain with an example :**

**If you want to add an alert message in admin Form:**

> ui/test_form.xml

```
<settings>
    <buttons>
        <button class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Label\Edit\DeleteButton" name="delete"/>
    </buttons>                
</settings>
```

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Label/Edit/DeleteButton.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Productlabel\Edit;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class DeleteButton extends GenericButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        $data = [];
        if ($this->getModelId()) {
            $data = [
                'label' => __('Delete'),
                'class' => 'delete',
                'on_click' => 'deleteConfirm(\'' . __(
                    'Are you sure you want to do this?'
                ) . '\', \'' . $this->getDeleteUrl() . '\')',
                'sort_order' => 20,
            ];
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get URL for delete button
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDeleteUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/delete', ['id' => $this->getModelId()]);
    }
}
```

You can also do it for all action just pass your block file path to under `<setting>` node in your `form.xml` and create block file same as given above.

**Display alert message in grid Mass Action:**

If you want to display a message in `mass action` in a grid listing then like below :

```
<action name="delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="routname/controler/massDelete" />
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Delete items</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
```

That's it! I hope it helps!

Comment: Do you know about how to add custom URL for cancel button?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show on MASS DELETE you can add a `message` item.

```
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">
                    your_listing.your_listing.your_index_columns.ids
                </item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">topic_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <action name="delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="route/controler/massDelete"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete
                            selected items?
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this worked, MagentoEE 2.2.6

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions">
    <action name="delete">
        <settings>
            <confirm>
                <message translate="true">Are you sure to delete selected items?</message>
                <title translate="true">Delete items</title>
            </confirm>
        </settings>
    </action>
</massaction>
```