# How to add alert box in admin form

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I want to add the confirm box while click save button in magento2 admin form.

How to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in the block file of the button

```
    $data = [];
    if ($this->getBlockId()) {
        $data = [
            'label' => __('Delete Block'),
            'class' => 'delete',
            'on_click' => 'deleteConfirm(\'' . __(
                'Are you sure you want to do this?'
            ) . '\', \'' . $this->getDeleteUrl() . '\', {"data": {}})',
            'sort_order' => 20,
        ];
    }
    return $data;
```

Comment: It's not working for save button

Comment: Can you please try xml way to add the confirmation box     https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264783/magento2-how-to-add-confirmation-alert-to-custom-field-in

Comment: It's only working for the delete button in admin from